# What is Dunsany satirizing with the "Historical Fact" in The King of Elfland's Daughter?

Tags: the-king-of-elflands-daugher, lord-dunsany

In [Lord Dunsany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Plunkett,_18th_Baron_of_Dunsany)'s best known work, *[The King of Elfland's Daughter](http://gutenberg.ca/ebooks/dunsany-kingofelflandsdaughter/dunsany-kingofelflandsdaughter-00-h.html)*, there is a strong motif of contrast between the mundane world (described over one hundred time as the "fields we know") and the dreamlike Elfland.  However, the nonmagical world where most of the book takes place is not exactly the real world either; the vale of Erl is not a real place, and (even apart from the presence of the Elfland border) there are many differences between Erl and the real world.  For example, there is something akin to Christianity in Erl, but the local cleric's title is "Freer," not "Friar."

Yet in chapter XX (entitled "A Historical Fact"), just after Orion, the half-elven lord of Erl, has managed, for the first time, to kill a unicorn that wandered over from Elfland, Dunsany includes this bizarre explanation of what the eponymous "Historical Fact" is:

> This was the horn that was sent in later years as a gift from the Pope to King Francis.  Benvenuto Cellini tells of it in his memoirs.  He tells how Pope Clement sent for him and a certain Tobbia, and ordered them to make designs for the setting of a unicorn's horn, the finest ever seen.  Judge then of Orion's delight when the horn of the first unicorn he ever took was such as to be esteemed generations later the finest ever seen, and in no less a city than Rome, with all her opportunities to acquire and compare such things.  For a number of these curious horns must have been available for the Pope to have selected for the gift the finest ever seen; but in the simpler days of my story the rarity of the horn was so great that unicorns were still considered fabulous.  The year of the gift to King Francis would be about 1530, the horn being mounted in gold; and the contract went to Tobbia and not to Benvenuto Cellini.  **I mention the date because there are those who care little for a tale if it be not here and there supported by history, and who even in history care more for fact than philosophy.  If any such reader have followed the fortunes of Orion so far he will be hungry by now for a date or a historical fact.**  As for the date, I give him 1530.  While for the historical fact I select that generous gift recorded by Benvenuto Cellini, because it may well be that just where he came to unicorns such a reader may have felt furthest away from history and have felt loneliest just at this point for want of historical things.  How the unicorn's horn found its way from the Castle of Erl, and in what hands it wandered, and how it came at last to the City of Rome, would of course make another book. [Bolding added]

This certainly seems to be poking fun at something, perhaps critiques aimed at Dunsany's earlier work.  In fact, it reminds me a bit of how Mark Twain famously skewered critics' commentary on *The Adventures of Tom Sawyer* with the famous author's note from *The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn*:

> Persons attempting to find a motive in this narrative will be prosecuted; persons attempting to find a moral in it will be banished; persons attempting to find a plot in it will be shot.

In Dunsany's passage, it certainly seems like he is satirizing something fairly specific.  So what is it?  And would the context have been more obvious to his readers in 1924?

Comment: I loved this bit. "Oh, by the way, it all really happened" out of nowhere. Wonderful. But you're right, the wording does sound like he's responding to something specific. And I'm not familiar with any of his other books either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Parodying himself

Dunsany's earliest works were a very lofty style - consider one of the first paragraphs in one of his earliest works, *[The Gods of Pegāna](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Gods_of_Peg%C4%81na)*:

> In the mists before the Beginning, Fate and Chance cast lots to decide whose the Game should be; and he that won strode through the mists to Māna-Yood-Sushāī and said: “Now make gods for Me, for I have won the cast and the Game is to be Mine.” Who it was that won the cast, and whether it was Fate or whether Chance that went through the mists before the Beginning to Māna-Yood-Sushāī — none knoweth.

It almost reminds one of the tone in, e.g., Tolkien's Silmarillion. Very high fantasy.

Later, he proceeded to almost make fun of his earlier high style - consider for example this passage from *[The Book of Wonder](http://www.public-library.uk/ebooks/16/24.pdf)*:

> The Gibbelins eat, as is well known, nothing less good than man. Their evil tower is joined to Terra Cognita, to the lands we know, by a bridge. Their hoard is beyond reason; avarice has no use for it; they have a separate cellar for emeralds and a separate cellar for sapphires; they have filled a hole with gold and dig it up when they need it. And the only use that is known for their ridiculous wealth is to attract to their larder a continual supply of food. In times of famine they have even been known to scatter rubies abroad, a little trail of them to some city of Man, and sure enough their larders would soon be full again.

After this, Dunsany turned more towards plays, and then finally towards writing novels. In this time he wrote *The King of Elfland's Daughter*. This is much more like Dunsany's earliest style, but that passage seems quite in contrast to it, with it almost matching his middling style. It could very well be this was intended as a private (or more public) joke on the whole situation.

### The "club tale"

In the same time as Dunsany wrote *The King of Elfland's Daughter*, he also began a new sort of fantasy writing - if I may quote Wikipedia:

> One of Dunsany's best-known characters was Joseph Jorkens, an obese middle-aged raconteur who frequented the fictional Billiards Club in London, and who would tell fantastic stories if someone would buy him a large whiskey and soda. From his tales, it was obvious that Mr Jorkens had travelled to all seven continents, was extremely resourceful, and well-versed in world cultures, but always came up short on becoming rich and famous. The Jorkens books, which sold well, were among the first of a type which was to become popular in fantasy and science fiction writing: extremely improbable "club tales" told at a gentleman's club or bar.

In these sorts of "club tales" it is common for the tale-teller to provide evidence that the tale actually occurred. See for example [this](http://www.michaelbroschat.com/Dunsany/OurDistantCousins.pdf) Jorkens story by Dunsany. Note the dates, the explanations for the plans working, and pieces of evidence - e.g.,

> “And you brought back nothing at all?” I asked. For there was the ring of truth in his story
> and I was hoping it could be proved.
> “Nothing except an old match-box broken in a very peculiar way. And, if you can’t see
> what broke it, that will prove nothing to you either. I’ll show it you later.”

Your quote, then, is an echo of that style.

### A Final Note

This is rather speculate-y even for my tastes, I'll update as I find more. I should note though that Dunsany published first drafts, so the consistency of his stories, and the presence of an explanation for this, is somewhat doubtful.

Answer (score 3):

Having read more of Dunsany's work—as well as contemporary criticisms of it—I am prepared to provide a (partial) answer to my own questions.

One of the things that made Dunsany's fantasy writing really innovative was the creation of completely new mythologies.  The publication of *[The Gods of Pegāna](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/8395/pg8395-images.html)* in 1905 was a landmark in fantasy literature, because the stories center on a completely invented pantheon of deities.  While this kinds of mythopoeia is commonplace in fantasy literature today, it was considered groundbreaking in the early twentieth century.

Much of the critical response to Dunsany's myth-making was positive.  However, there were reviewers that criticized *The Gods of Pegāna* (and the thematically similar works he wrote later on, such as *[Time and the God](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/8183/pg8183-images.html)s*)—on the basis that the stories, with entirely invented mythoi, were too far from real legends to be compelling.  The section about the unicorn horn, in which Dunsany specifically ties the events in *The King of Elfland's Daughter* to the real world, seem like a jab at the reviewers who has criticized his earlier stories for being too esoteric.